# Kaczorowski's Paper on Distribution of Primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, paper-request

I am looking for a digital copy of the following paper by Jerzy Kaczorowski: ON THE DISTRIBUTION OF PRIMES (mod4) 
https://www.degruyter.com/view/j/anly.1995.15.issue-2/anly.1995.15.2.159/anly.1995.15.2.159.xml

The above link is the only place where I could find it (which is behind a paywall). Thus, if anyone has a digital copy I would very much appreciate the help.

Apologies if this is not the correct forum for this question. Please let me know and I can move it.

Comment: Do you have access to a library? Many libraries have an interlibrary loan facility.

Comment: I too would be interested in a copy.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I do not have access to any college libraries currently. I'll try to see if my local public library can help out

Comment: @GregMartin: I can forward it you if I get my hands on it. Btw, your paper (Prime number races) with Andrew Granville got me interested in this topic. It was an excellent read.

Comment: Did you try contacting the author?

Comment: @primefinder Thank you very much! The interesting subject definitely sells itself :)

Comment: I (and sci-hub, to which I have no relation to :-)) have a copy. Send me an email (may be found via my profile) to ask for it.